# How to find string in MySQL databe using Python

Tags: python, mysql, if-statement

I need to check every word from string in MySQL database. But it never found it, even if the word is in database. Can someone help to solve it?

```
mycursor = db.cursor()
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM table")
table1 = mycursor.fetchall()

string = "This is test string"
string = string.split(" ")
for i in string:
   if i in table1:
       print(i + "FOUND")
       
   else:
       print(i + "NOT FOUND")
```

Comment: Do you really need to check the string against every column in the table? It would make more sense to select the specific column you care about.

Answer (score 0):

`fetchall()` returns a list of tuples, each tuple consists of all the columns of a single row of the table. So you need to check all the tuple elements.

```
for i in string:
    if any(i in row for row in table1):
        print(f"{i} FOUND")
    else:
        print(f"{i} NOT FOUND")
```

If you only care about a specific column, you could change your query to just select that column. Then you can make the search more efficient by putting that into a Python set.

```
mycursor = db.cursor()
mycursor.execute("SELECT columnName FROM table")
table1 = set(row[0] for row in mycursor.fetchall())

string = "This is test string"
string = string.split(" ")
for i in string:
   if i in table1:
       print(i + "FOUND")
   else:
       print(i + "NOT FOUND")
```